# How can I map an Object of Objects using React JSX to create a time table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object, jsx

**How to map object of objects**

You are given a timetable of a class 12th student. You need to display the timetable of the student in the form of a table. The given timeTable data consists of objects of a particular day and each day consists of objects which show subject details across a particular hour.

I was doing this project but I'm unable to map the objects of objects to display it in the timetable feature

```
const timeTable = {
      Monday: {
        9: {
            subject: "Maths",
            teacher: "Brijesh Mishra",
           time: "1 hour"
          },
         10: {
          subject: "Physics",
           teacher: "Sumit Yadav",
            time: "1 hour"
           },
          11: {
         subject: "Chemistry",
         teacher: "Vedanti Joshi",
          time: "1 hour"
        },
        13: {
           subject: "English Litrature",
           teacher: "Mayur Pandey",
          time: "1 hour"
         },
        14: {
          subject: "Hindi Vyakaran",
          teacher: "Sony Desai",
         time: "1 hour"
         },
        15: {
         subject: "PT",
          teacher: "Sonu Tyagi",
         time: "1 hour"
        }
        },
       Tuesday: {
         9: {
          subject: "Physics",
          teacher: "Sumit Yadav",
          time: "1 hour"
        },
        10: {
         subject: "Hindi Sahitya",
          teacher: "Ramesh Jha",
         time: "1 hour"
       },
       11: {
            subject: "Environtal Studies",
            teacher: "Rakesh Prakash",
           time: "1 hour"
          },
         13: {
             subject: "Biology",
             teacher: "Kuldeep Narayan",
           time: "1 hour"
         },
        14: {
          subject: "Maths",
         teacher: "Brijesh Mishra",
         time: "1 hour"
         },
        15: {
            subject: "Physics Practical",
            teacher: "Sumit Yadav",
           time: "1 hour"
         }
        },
         Wednesday: {
       9: {
         subject: "Chemistry",
         teacher: "Vedanti Joshi",
         time: "1 hour"
       },
        10: {
          subject: "English Grammar",
         teacher: "Aditi Upasane",
         time: "1 hour"
       },
       11: {
          subject: "Maths",
         teacher: "Brijesh Mishra",
         time: "1 hour"
       },
       13: {
      subject: "English Litrature",
      teacher: "Mayur Pandey",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    14: {
      subject: "Physics",
      teacher: "Sumit Yadav",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    15: {
      subject: "Chemistry Practical",
      teacher: "Vedanti Joshi",
      time: "1 hour"
    }
  },
  Thursday: {
    9: {
      subject: "Biology",
      teacher: "Kuldeep Narayan",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    10: {
      subject: "Hindi Sahitya",
      teacher: "Ramesh Jha",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    11: {
      subject: "Chemistry",
      teacher: "Vedanti Joshi",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    13: {
      subject: "Maths",
      teacher: "Brijesh Mishra",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    14: {
      subject: "Physics",
      teacher: "Sumit Yadav",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    15: {
      subject: "Biology Practical",
      teacher: "Kuldeep Narayan",
      time: "1 hour"
    }
  },
  Friday: {
    9: {
      subject: "English Litrature",
      teacher: "Mayur Pandey",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    10: {
      subject: "Hindi Sahitya",
      teacher: "Ramesh Jha",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    11: {
      subject: "English Grammar",
      teacher: "Aditi Upasane",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    13: {
      subject: "Biology",
      teacher: "Kuldeep Narayan",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    14: {
      subject: "Hindi Vyakaran",
      teacher: "Sony Desai",
      time: "1 hour"
    },
    15: {
      subject: "PT",
      teacher: "Sonu Tyagi",
      time: "1 hour"
    }
  }
};
```

`
I'm making a time table using React.I have to insert all days subject in a row[Time table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I5cA.png)

I tried to map them but I'm unable to do it